# Is Basic Authorization always using the same "success condition"?

Tags: authorization, basic-authentication

I have some code that looks at "[Basic Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)" requests from many different sites.
I want to know if I can make the following assumptions:

- A successful response (credentials are correct) will **always** have response code 200 OK
- A failed response (incorrect credentials) will **always** have response code 401 Unauthorized

Are the above fair assumptions, or is the success/fail conditions configurable per site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are other possible response codes.

According to [the official spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-3.2), there can also be the error code `407`.

Also, on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication#access_forbidden):

> If a (proxy) server receives invalid credentials, it should respond with a `401 Unauthorized` or with a `407 Proxy Authentication Required`, and the user may send a new request or replace the Authorization header field.
>
> If a (proxy) server receives valid credentials that are inadequate to access a given resource, the server should respond with the `403 Forbidden` status code. Unlike `401 Unauthorized` or `407 Proxy Authentication Required`, authentication is impossible for this user and browsers will not propose a new attempt.
>
> In all cases, the server may prefer returning a `404 Not Found` status code, to hide the existence of the page to a user without adequate privileges or not correctly authenticated.

Besides that, I'm quite sure that an actual successful attempt will result in status code `200`.

Comment: Thanks! The success response is actually the most important one for me. Do you have any source for the why it will always be 200 in that case?

Comment: @Idos I don't see any reason it wouldn't/shouldn't be `200`, but I'm confident it's configurable.